# boost asio tcp ip write

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I am using this code http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime1/src.html 
in order to make a client and talk to a server.

I am using the following code to send a message

```
   boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(msg), ignored_error);
```

The problem that I have is that if I declare a string msg= "test 123"; and send it, the server will get "test 123"
But if if use cin << msg and input test 123 the server receives two messages :

```
   test
   123
```

The same applies for char[]

I am compiling at C++ 11 if it does matter using -lboost_system parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input with `>>` separates on space. So input like `test 123` will need two reads using `>>`.

If you want to read a whole line then use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).